# Filter json payload based upon filter array

Tags: dataweave

Input payload

```
{
    "student": {
        "id": 123,
        "class": "seventh",
        "activities": {
            "curriculum" {
                "certification": ["Cyber-security", "Python"],
                "year": [2021, 2021]
            },
            "extra-curriculum": {
                "field": ["volleyball"]
            },
            "others": ["student-forum"]
        }
    }
}

filterList-
"filterList": ["id", "class", "certification", "year", "field", "others"]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "class": "seventh",
    "certification": ["Cyber-security", "Python"],
    "year": [2021, 2021]
    "field": ["volleyball"]
    "others": ["student-forum"]
}
```

This can be done by tracking the key eg:

```
("year":payload.student.activites.curriculum.year) if( filterList contains "year")
```

But this is very lengthy and boring process when you have huge payload. Is there any generalized way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do it. Filtering would be easy with a recursive function, pattern matching and the filterObject() function, but there is a hidden complexity. You are not just filtering but also flattening the object hierarchy. The trick is to do both separately and merge the results.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import mergeWith from dw::core::Objects
var filterList=["id", "class", "certification", "year", "field", "others"]

fun subEntries(o, filter)=
    o 
        filterObject ((value, key, index) -> value is Object)
        mapObject ((value, key, index) -> filteKeyRecursive(value, filter) )

fun filteKeyRecursive(x, filter) =
    x match {
        case is Object -> 
            x filterObject ((value, key, index) -> filter contains  (key as String) ) mergeWith subEntries(x, filter)
        else -> x
  }
---
filteKeyRecursive(payload, filterList)
```

Comment: Hi @aled, Thanks, for the solution and explanation. This works as expected.
I see that you answer on all my queries. Just curious about how you find such new functions, do you got through docs or it just what you gain from experience.

Comment: You are welcome @SatyamPisal. If you are asking about the functions I created it is experience and trying to reuse behavior and encapsulate in a functional way. For example the main function is so we can encapsulate the expected behavior and reuse withouth fixed data. When I understood that I needed to join to parts of data I wrote the first part as an expression, though I could have put that into a function too (`x filterObject ((value, key, index) -> filter contains  (key as String) )`). Then I created a function for the second part to be able to try different things.

Comment: For functions included in DataWeave I use the reference documentation https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-functions

Comment: Thanks a lot, look forward to gain such amount of knowledge and experience

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if an alternative to the recursive function is needed ,then it could be easily done with a Descendants selector.PFB a shorter script.

```
%dw 2.0
var filterList = ["id", "class", "certification", "year", "field", "others"]
output application/json  
---
(filterList map (v0, k0) -> {
  (v0): (payload.."$(v0)")[0]
}) reduce ((item, obj = {}) -> obj ++ item)
```

I hope this helps you.Please Let me know.
[image]